# Proof - set identity

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have a problem with a few set identities. We are to prove them by cases. I grasp how to do that for the basic commutative, distributive and absorption laws but have no idea how the rule works for the identities based on a set complement. Here are the examples:

$A \cap B = A \setminus(A \setminus B)$

$(A \cup B) \setminus B = A \setminus B$

I'm not sure whether some proof by contradiction is needed here. I'll be extremely grateful for your help.

Comment: Do you know De Morgan's law?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways of proving set equality ($A=B$) that I know of:

$1)$ Using [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws), distributive and other laws directly.

$2)$ Proving $A\subseteq B$ and $B\subseteq A$ (remember that $A\subseteq B \iff \forall x\in A(x\in B)$).

$3)$ Using [Venn Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram).

My proof uses $1)$.

$$\begin{align}A\setminus(A\setminus B)&=A\cap(A\cap B^c)^{c}=A\cap(A^c\cup B)\\&=(A\cap A^c)\cup(A\cap B)=(\varnothing)\cup (A\cap B)=A\cap B\end{align}$$

$$\begin{align}(A\cup B)\setminus B&=(A\cup B)\cap B^c=(A\cap B^c)\cup (B\cap B^c)\\&=(A\cap B^c)\cup(\varnothing)=A\cap B^c=A\setminus B\end{align}$$

We've used [De Morgan's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws). Also $A^c$ is the [complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)) of $A$.